# How to catch all mails addressed to different mail addresses containing same pattern in postfix

Tags: email, virtual, postfix-mta, aliases, catch-all

I want to ask how i can catch all mails addressed to different mail addresses containing same pattern to one real mail address using postfix.

E.g.:

I want to catch:

```
john.smith.test1@domain.com

john.smith.test2@domain.com 

john.smith.test3@domain.com

...

john.smith.test100@domain.com
```

And forward it to;

```
john.smith@domain.com
```

I use postfix and virtual aliases.

```
# /etc/postfix/main.cf
...
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
...
```

It is possible to do somthing like code below?

```
# /etc/postfix/virtual
david.guest@domain.com david.guest@domain.com
jack.wilder@domain.com jack.wilder@domain.com
adam.stone@domain.com  adam.stone@domain.com
john.smith@domain.com  john.smith@domain.com

john.smith*@domain.com john.smith@domain.com
```

I need to catch all mails starting with *john.smith* and forward it to *john.smith@domain.com*

Thanks for help.